# Importing react into pages in next.js (and also React and CRA apps)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app with several pages in it. All of the pages look similar.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import  from "components/Wrapper";

export default class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Wrapper />;
  }
}
```

I would like to refactor it using functional component.

I read [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/next-js-react-server-side-rendering-done-right-f9700078a3b6) that you don't have to import react package here in a page due to next.js routing system. Next.js docs also show examples without react import on a page component, but no explanation given.

Can you clarify please. Is it necessary to import React at all in this case? Can I remove the import React line?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, actually it is still a complicated issue for all of us to realise when to use `import React from "react";` and when not to in Next.js apps. But according to [Tim Neutkens](https://vercel.com/about/timneutkens) co-author of Next.js, in [this thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12964#issuecomment-629642157) he mentioned:

> Next.js automatically adds the React import when JSX is used indeed. However, keep in mind that we still need to `import React from 'react'` when the React variable is used.

So this will show us, that whenever we want to use the JSX feature alone from React we do not have to `import React from 'react'` and Next.js will implicitly import it for us, but in any other case, we have to do that.

## Update

Since the release of [`react v17.*.*`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html), there is no need to `import React from 'react'` to use only JSX in the React and CRA apps, but you still need to import it for the usage of the hooks and other compartments that React offers with destructured named imports.

#### NPM libraries/packages

Though you will still need it if you want to create an npm package with react because [under the hood](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-different-in-the-new-transform) it is the `react-scripts` job to do the automatic imports and `babel` or `rollup` won't do this on their own and they've just transpile the provided code. Keep in mind even in this case the usage of `import React from 'react'` is discouraged because the [support will be dropped in the upcoming versions](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1308739731551858689), so it is highly recommended to use `import * as React from 'react'` in these cases.

Comment: So as I understand import React will be added in any case after jsx is transpiled

Comment: @kilogram Yea, that's true. But for instance, you will still need to import it when you want to use `useState`. Because if you won't it will throw an error and it won't reach the transpilng part.

Comment: What's the bundle size effects of removing/adding import React line though? I've removed import React statements app wide recently from my Nextjs project however bundle size went 8kb higher, weird...

Comment: @sed In most cases, in a regular CRA (I'm not sure about the Vite version), it should not affect the bundle size. However, in a Nextjs application, removing a React import may be transformed to `import * as React from 'react'`, which will import the whole export from the `'react'` library, by default due to the Webpack configuration, it will drop all the unnecessary imports in tree shaking phase. This is not the case in the Nextjs app so it won't decrease extra unused imports. This is just a scenario I imagine happening under the hood.