# VSCode keeps asking to import React on NextJS and React 17 apps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I've already set the following rules to off in my *eslintrc.json* file:

[image]

But whenever I press *ctrl+.* to try importing a component from a different file vscode suggests me to import React.

[image]

is there any way to stop this from happening?

below are the plugins I'm using with the .eslintrc.json:

[image]

Comment: Did you install eslint VSCode plugin to allow them to parse your eslintrc?

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem to be a problem with eslint to be honest. I think it's the default vscode behaviour for jsx.

Comment: Maybe you have to add your Next.js's pages/component extension (.js/.ts) into     `"react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }], //should add ".ts" if typescript project`

Comment: It already has .js, .jsx and .tsx

Comment: Can you paste your full `.eslintrc.json`? Do you have another plugin (airbnb react,...) that may cause conflict with your rules?

Comment: I've added the plugins in it. When I try the whole .eslintrc.json it says I have more code then text and that I should reformat the question.

Comment: Not sure if this thread/helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63090441/2312051

Comment: there could be multiple extensions which may ask you to 'import React'... can you share the screenshot of the Output panel of vscode (Ctrl + shift + U)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an issue with ESLint - this is an issue with Typescript. [It's tracked here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41762) and you can confirm that even if you disable ESLint for your project you'll get this error and that bad suggestion. At the moment there's no workaround other but it will hopefully be fixed in TS4.3. I will update this answer if a workaround or solution is released.

Comment: This does appear to be fixed if you're using the nightly build of TS (as of 3/30). Hopefully 4.3 production will be out soon with a real fix.